# incomplete document for java.util.stream package in java8

Tags: java

In the source code, clearly there is an `AbstractPipeline` class which implements the `BaseStream` interface, but this is not documented:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html

Also, the abstract class `ReferencePipeline` implements the `Stream`interface, which is not mentioned:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html

Moreover, in the package summary these abstract classes are not mentioned at all:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Given the fact that abstract classes and their relationship with interfaces are documented clearly in other packages like `java.util`:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html

Can we say that it is a bug for java8 stream documentation?

Comment: Those classes that you refer to are package-private, not `public`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the classes you mention have package-level access. This means that they are not public classes and are effectively an implementation detail, not part of the public API. You can not (easily) use these classes directly in your code even if you know about them.

This is not a bug, but rather a deliberate choice. The are many base classes and interfaces that have package level access because they are used throughout a package (including `java.util`). Unless you delve into the source code of a particular JRE implementation, you will not know about them.